# Bootstrap Modal Validator Not Working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with the form that I put on my Bootstrap Modal. I am really newbie in web programming.

The purpose of my code is showing some error notification when user did not insert text into text field.

This is the form inside my Modal,

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="add_room" role="form">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">

  <div class="modal-body">

    <?php 
       $attributes = array("id" => "addform", "name" => "addform");
       echo form_open_multipart("", $attributes);
    ?>
    <div class="form-group has-error">
        <input class="form-control" id="txt" name="txt" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group last">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"/>Submit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>


</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#addform').on('submit', function(e) {
    var txt = $('#txt');

    // Check if there is an entered value
    if(!txt.val()) {
      // Add errors highlight
      txt.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');

      // Stop submission of the form
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      // Remove the errors highlight
      txt.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
    }
  });
```

Totally, the code is refer to this problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968361/validate-input-text-in-bootstrap-modal). But somehow maybe I missed something.

The problem is, every time I press the submit button, the modal is closed. All I need is, it should show some notification/red line according to the JavaScript.

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Does your page reloads (follows form action) or just modal is hidden?

Comment: @Justinas yes it does reload

Comment: Have you tried returning false at the end?

Comment: @Justinas where i have to add that?

Comment: At the end of function (for testing if it works, later move inside `if` body)

Comment: @Justinas no it didn't work. Can you help me from this https://jsfiddle.net/5bf8bdg6/13/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78674/discussion-between-lloistborn-and-justinas).

Comment: Thanks @Justinas , final code https://jsfiddle.net/5bf8bdg6/31/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is, you want to make sure you include all the js files that you need. Something like:

```
<script src="[path]/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="[path]/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="[path]/formValidation.min.js"></script>
```

Now, all you need is to bind the validation to your form, like:

```
$('your-form-identifier').formValidation({
    // some validation options, according to the documentation of the plugin you use
});
```

Depending on the validation tool you will be using, you might need to add attributes to your inputs, specifying the type of validation that you need. For example: `<input type="text" ... required />` means user will need to enter some data; `<input type="email" ... />` means user will need to enter a valid email etc.

Check out this article:
http://formvalidation.io/examples/modal/

Please provide a fiddle or more code and I can try to give you some more details on what you need to do.

Comment: I don't have one, and i got problem when trying to put my code in fiddle.

Comment: Just do the fiddle with html and javascript, don't try to include the php part. I started it for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/5bf8bdg6/2/

Comment: Thanks @Ioana Cucuruzan

So, this is the full code https://jsfiddle.net/5bf8bdg6/13/
But, remember to use jQuery 1.7.2 and check the bootstrap 2.0.2

Comment: I can't get it to work with jQuery 1.7.2. What you can do is use a validation plugin http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/ or http://jqueryvalidation.org/ In any case, I recommend upgrading to a more recent jquery version.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it did work now. The problem is i'm not put the js and script properly. Final code https://jsfiddle.net/5bf8bdg6/31/

Comment: Hi @lloistborn - if this answer resolves your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that (a) the community knows that you are happy, and (b) both you and the answerer get some reputation on StackOverflow. Many thanks.